# Adding array value to OnItemClickListener() in Activity

Tags: java, android, listview, listactivity

I am using this code :

```
final ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

            HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);                   
            Intent intent = new Intent(TestActivity.this, TestDetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("id_card", o.get("id_card"));
            intent.putExtra("card_title", o.get("card_title"));
            intent.putExtra("card_number", o.get("card_number"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

I'm using `HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>)` to get some values which i will be passing to another activity with intent.

It works when I use `ListActivity` but I don't know how to implement it in Activity, please help me.

Comment: plese give ans about how you get hash map which u retrive from previous activity

Comment: Can you be clear on what you want exactly?

Answer (score 3):

Because [getListView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#getListView%28%29) is the method of [**ListActivity**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html)

Which means when you using

> final ListView lv = getListView();

ListView will get initialized with `super`, while your simple `Activity` class doesn't contain any ListView.

ListActivity->  *ListActivity hosts a ListView object that can be bound to different data sources*

To use the same in Activity class then you must use explicit ListView and mapped it with ID

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/list_view"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

now you can initialized like this

```
final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.its work. but i want to adding array data to OnItemClickListener(). i use Hashmap in ListActivity, how do i implement it when use Activity?

Comment: already mentioned in answer(take explicit ListView), you can refer this http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 0):

The call to `getListView()` only works in `ListActivity`. You will need to get access to your ListView a different way. Implement this method in your Activity:

```
public ListView getListView()
{
    return findViewById(android.R.id.list);
}
```

(or if your list id is something else, use that id instead)